# Function wp_generate_attachment_metadata returns always empty array in ajax function

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have searched far and wide, but have not found a solution.
I have a real estate ad insertion form, I need to be able to upload photos of the listings. I can upload the photos to the server via ajax, return the filenames in a textarea and always via ajax, after submitting the form, I can upload the photos to wordpress and attach them to the ad
The only problem is that it does not generate the photo metadata, wp_generate_attachment_metadata always returns an empty array.
I can't find a solution about it. I have another plugin with a similar form, but there I post the form not via ajax, but with the action = "post", and I can safely generate the metadata.

This is the code with which I insert the attachments and link them to the newly created post.

Hope someone can help me

```
//$filename = domoria-torino-strada-della-fornace-druento-15.jpg
if ($filename != '') {
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();     
    $filename_path = $wp_upload_dir['path'] .'/'. $filename;         
    $filename_url = $wp_upload_dir['url'] .'/'. $filename;
    

    $guid = $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename_path );
                                        
    $attachment = array(
                        'guid'=> $guid,
                        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'post_title' => $filename,
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'inherit',
                        'post_parent' => $post_id
                    );
    
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename_path);
    if($iter === 0){
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    }
    $ids [] = $attach_id; //this array needs for an ACF field
    
    //filename_path = home/uxo80ef6/domains/homeprime.sviluppo.host/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/domoria-torino-strada-della-fornace-druento-15.jpg
    //$attach_id = 629
    
    $file_uploaded_path = get_attached_file($attach_id);
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_uploaded_path );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    $iter++;
}
```

UPDATE: The problem is due to getimagesize called by wp_generate_attachment_metadata that can't find the file by file_path, however the file is on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote some parts of the code you posted:

1. change hardcoded `post_mime_type` with `wp_check_filetype()` instead.
2. rename some of the variables to: `$file_name`, `$file_path`, `$parent_post_id`
3. removed unused `$filename_url`
4. added `$parent_post_id` as the third argument into `wp_insert_attachment()`
5. removed `get_attached_file()` function and used `$file_path` for `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`

```
<?php
// $file_name = domoria-torino-strada-della-fornace-druento-15.jpg
if (!empty($file_name)) {
    // The ID of the post this attachment is for.
    // eg. $parent_post_id = 37;

    // Get the path to the upload directory.
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $file_path = $wp_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file_name;

    // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_path), null);

    // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($file_path),
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_title($file_name),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the attachment.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path, $parent_post_id);

    // Set the first attachment as Featured image.
    if ($iter === 0) {
        set_post_thumbnail($parent_post_id, $attach_id);
    }

    // ACF field array data.
    $ids[] = $attach_id;

    // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_path);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

    $iter++;
}
```